# Are there any "reserved" aura attributes for Aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I had this on my previous question where id I defined the attribute "required" as a boolean validation would fail is there a list of these "reserved" attributes and their names for LWC Aura

Comment: Again, it's either Aura **or** LWC. They are two different technologies and follow different rules. Presumably, you're asking about Aura, so LWC should not be in the question title.

Answer (score 1):

In Aura, you must begin attributes with a letter or underscore, and must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm).

In LWC, you must not start any attribute name with `on`, `aria`, or `data`. You may not use the specific attribute names `slot`, `part`, or `is`. It is recommended that you do not start with an uppercase character, because it requires special syntax to address such properties. It is recommended you do not use [HTML global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), but you can use them if you decorate them with `@api`. You must begin attributes with a letter or underscore, and must only contain letters, numbers, and underscores, as in Aura. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_names).

`required` is not specifically reserved, and aside from a small handful of restrictions, you can use any names you want. In Aura, you can specifically use any name that meets the rules without reservation. As far as I know, there's no restriction on even using HTML global attributes if you really want to, although I wouldn't recommend it.